# loadHTMLString for a simple WKWebView crashed at runtime with error WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 0), reason 3

Tags: wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying to work with a simple WKWebView with a single button, which upon clicking should callback to the Swift via JavaScript. However, I see the following log in Xcode console and the view loads empty WKWebView:

> - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=0] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 0), reason 3
> - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=0] WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason = 3
> - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=84636] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 84636), reason 3
> - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=84636] WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason = 3
> - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=84636] WebPageProxy::tryReloadAfterProcessTermination: process crashed and
>   the client did not handle it, not reloading the page because we
>   reached the maximum number of attempts

My code to initialize the WKWebView and setting up the callback looks like so:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "callback")
        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        wkWebView.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
        self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)
        
        let htmlStr = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">My Button</button><script type=\"text/javascript\">function myFunction() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.callback.postMessage('clicked!'); }</script></body></html>"
        self.wkWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlStr, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took a while to understand that — because my app is sandboxed — I needed to enable the Network connections under Signing & Capabilities, which in turn add the proper entitlements to the project that launches the WKWebView with the much awaited `My Button`. **I also now get the callback when clicking this button!**

[image: Capabilities to enable]

[image: Sample App Launched with button]

Hope this helps someone who's in this same situation.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar error in our application. Our use case was that we were using webView to render HTML websites and then taking snapshots of it. For each render, we were creating a new `WKWebView` instance.

Users reported that as more and more renders happened, it became slower and slower. We witnessed that after many creations of `WKWebView`, it would fail with a message in the console:

```
WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason=Crash
```

If we tried to create a new `WKWebView` after that and take a snapshot of it, snapshot completion would be called after ±10 minutes with an error code 1, stating that the error is unknown.

The solution was one of the following:

- Clear the cache (`WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData`) after we
  receive a delegate call in `webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate` or
  before creating a new `WKWebView`
- For some reason, it also works if you do not create a new instance of `WKWebView` and instead re-use the same one